# Openshift tomcat killed after one day

Tags: openshift

I have deployed a java web application in openshift using tomcat server.Application is running fine. But after 1-2 days automatically tomcat server gets killed.so i have to manually start the server.can any one tell me what is going wrong here.i'm using free account.
Thanks,
A.G.Ishara

Answer (score 0):

Applications on the free account get idled automatically after 24 hours of no external http requests. The application should then automatically restart itself once a request is made.

Comment: Thanks for the help.And if i do pay will it not be idle?

Comment: All you would need to do is sign up for the Bronze plan (which is still free).